# How to use drupal_set_html_head in a page created though my module

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I have my module like this

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => 'mymodule',
        'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('access content')
    );

    return $items;
}

function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['text'] = array(
      '#markup' => 'mymodule content'
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Which will create a page mysite.com/mymodule.
I now want to add a meta tag to this page using drupal_set_html_head.

Anyone know where to place the drupal_set_html_head function call?

Comment: In your form function is fine

Comment: BTW You're missing `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form'` in your router item

Comment: @Clive yes it worked! Please make it as an Answer so that I can make it as the correct one!

Comment: @Clive, I have a plain text page. There fore I think I don't need a callback! But adding drupal_set_html_head to the form function worked!

Comment: Hey @Clive Why don't you copy the comment "In your form function is fine" to an answer so I can tick it as the correct answer and thereby you can get your reputation increased?

Comment: @BuntuLinux You do need the page callback. Should be set to drupal_get_form. Also I don't think Clive is in desperate need to any more rep :)